# expo React native navigation, screen stuck at default logo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'    
import Registrar from './pantallas/Registrar'; //register screen
import Principal from './pantallas/Principal'; // main screen after login    
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

export default function App()  {
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator(); 
  
  return(
    
  <NavigationContainer >
      
      <Stack.Group
        initialRouteName="Registrar"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown : false }}>            
        <Stack.Screen name="Registrar" component={Registrar} />            
        <Stack.Screen name="Principal" component={Principal} />          
      </Stack.Group>
    
    </NavigationContainer>
  )   
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, make sure you install `react-native-gesture-handler` and import it. Please see the stack-navigator docs for more info: [stack-navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator)

From the docs: "To finalize installation of `react-native-gesture-handler`, add the following at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as `index.js` or `App.js`: `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`"

Another thing I recommend is to use `@react-navigation/stack` rather than native-stack. Native stack causes issues when navigating between screens, whereas stack is known to be smoother and easier to use. The docs will explain everything.

Please reply if you have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I didn't install all packages required for navigation. It worked locally but stucked as apk file.

The documentation recommends you first install:
`npm install react-native-gesture-handler`
then ensure the first import at the top of your App.js (or similar) is
`import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

And you will need to optionally install masked view if you are using UIKit style animations:
`npm install @react-native-masked-view/masked-view`

Also note that you need to ensure that your pods are linked - while this happens automatically in later versions of react, you may need to run this command to link them:
`npx pod-install ios`